# Directional derivative help

Tags: derivatives

Im on the mountain 
$$ z= e^{-2x^2-y^2} $$ at the point $$ (1/2,1/\sqrt{2},e^{-1}) $$
which direction should i go,so that i will remain at the same hieght line
????

thanks

hint
the vector should be at XY plane

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** you want the vector $\bf v$ such that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial {\bf v}}(p) = 0 $, where $p$ is the given point.

Comment: thats what i thought, but i dont understand why its true?
please explain,

Comment: @uberStyx0. You want to keep $z$ constant and move, don't you ?

Comment: @ Claude_Leibovici i also know that
but why it should be equals to zero, theres something basic that im missing,if its equals to zero, doesnt it means that the theres no movement at all?

Comment: The direcional derivative is the derivative of the function $$t \mapsto f(p + t{\bf v})$$ so, this derivative being zero means that, in the $\bf v$ direction specifically, the derivative is zero, hence there is no variation *in this direction*.

Comment: Great!!!!, thanks
but i have i have got something else, i said that u=a+b(vector)
and i got $$ -2e^{-1}a+e^{-1}*(-\sqrt(2))b $$
but how do i find what is a and b?